# How to get only specific object of an array of object in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
  "data": {
    "category": "mobile",
    "products": [
      {
        "title": "Redmi Note 10 Pro"
      },
      {
        "title": "Redmi Note 100 Profile"
      }
    ]
  },
  "user": {
    "name": "username"
  }
}
```

How to get only specific object.
Mongodb

I just want object who have the category as `"mobile"`
and title as `"Redmi Note 100 Profile"`

Result expected:

```
{
  "data": {
    "category": "mobile",
    "products":{
        "title": "Redmi Note 100 Profile"
      }
  },
  "user": {
    "name": "username"
  }
}
```

I just don't want this object

```
{
 "title": "Redmi Note 10 Pro"
}
```

I'm using this to get

```
db.collection("products").aggregate([{
              "$unwind": "$data"
            },
              {
                "$match": {
                  "data.category": "mobile",
                  "data.products.title": "Redmi Note 100 Profile",
                }
              }])
            .toArray();
```

But, it's give me 2 object ?

```
{
  "data": {
    "category": "mobile",
    "products": [
      {
        "title": "Redmi Note 10 Pro"
      },
      {
        "title": "Redmi Note 100 Profile"
      }
    ]
  },
  "user": {
    "name": "username"
  }
}
```

How to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` framework with `$unwind` to unwind the products array and `$match` to filter out

Working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WfFoNgq257A)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$data.products"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "data.products.title": "Smartphone 1000 Pro Max Ultra Mega"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: i have update my code as you answer. But it's work for some field, but sometimes it's not work. So i have edited my question with my new problem, please check yourself and solve my problem.

Comment: You cannot `"$unwind": "$data"` as `data` is not an array. You need to do this `"$unwind": "$data.products"`

Comment: It's worked but, it's not giving the "user" & "data" object as i mentioned.

Comment: ok, yoou want like this `"products": [`? I mean products in array, that's the only difference?

Comment: No, I'm asking, i need ```"data"``` & ```"user"``` object also. But it's just giving me the ```"data"``` object, where is ```"user":{}```

Comment: It should give user object as well, please check the playground, it's returning both https://mongoplayground.net/p/WfFoNgq257A

Comment: Yeah, it's worked.. that's my fault, i was created some function that is why...